# ICU BreakIterator::createWordInstance Always sets the error code to "U_USING_DEFAULT_WARNING"

Tags: c++, icu

I'm trying to set up a wrapper for ICU's BreakIterator class to do boundary analysis, and I'm running into an odd issue during the initialization.

After setting up the Break Iterator, the error code status always gets set to U_USING_DEFAULT_WARNING.

According to the documentation:

> U_USING_DEFAULT_WARNING indicates that the default locale data was used; neither the requested locale nor any of its fall back locales could be found.

But the locales I've tried (en_US, ja_JP) are definitely valid and present on my system. They even show up in ICU's list from getAvailableLocales. But the error still gets set.

Here's my code, more or less:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <algorithm>
#include <unicode/brkiter.h>
#include <unicode/locid.h>


class WordIterator
{
    icu::UnicodeString _u16Data;
    std::unique_ptr<icu::BreakIterator> _itr = nullptr;
    bool _word;
    int32_t _begin, _cur, _next;
    UErrorCode _err;
public:
    WordIterator(const std::string& data, const icu::Locale& locale)
    {
        _u16Data = icu::UnicodeString::fromUTF8(data);
        _err = U_ZERO_ERROR;
        _itr.reset(icu::BreakIterator::createWordInstance(locale, _err));
        if (U_FAILURE(_err)) {
            throw std::runtime_error("Failed to create iterator");
        }

        _itr->setText(_u16Data);
        _begin = _itr->first();
        _cur = _begin;
        _next = _itr->next();
    }
    auto getError() const {
        return _err;
    }
};


int main()
{
    std::string locale_name = "en_US";
    std::cerr << "Testing locale: " << locale_name << "\n";
    int count = 0;
    auto locales = icu::Locale::getAvailableLocales(count);
    auto lc = std::find_if(locales, locales+count, [locale_name](icu::Locale search) {
            auto name = search.getName();
            auto code = std::string{name};
            return code == locale_name;
    });
    if (lc != locales+count) {
        std::cerr << "Locale was found.\n";
    }
    WordIterator br{"This is a test.", icu::Locale::createCanonical(locale_name.c_str())};
    if (br.getError() == U_USING_DEFAULT_WARNING) {
        std::cerr << "Default warning.\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Is there some extra initialization I need to do somewhere? U_FAILURE thinks it's successful, at least.

I should mention, I'm testing on Ubuntu 22.04 with ICU 70.1, if that makes any difference.

Comment: please show a [mre]

Answer (score 1):

When invoking `icu::BreakIterator::createWordInstance` the library searches its internal resource bundles for the required `"boundaries"` rule set (the one with type `"word"`). This step performs also a [fallback](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/locale/#fallback) on the given locale to find such a rule set.

You can invoke the method `getLocale(ULOC_ACTUAL_LOCALE, get_status)` on the returned break iterator instance, to assess what *actual* locale is being used. 99% of the time, you will find that is the locale with an empty name (root rules are being applied).

You should not consider a *warning* the result code `U_USING_DEFAULT_WARNING` of `BreakIterator::createXxxInstance` as **only a few locales have [a stored rule set](https://github.com/unicode-org/icu/tree/main/icu4c/source/data/brkitr/rules)**.

> Most locales fall back to root rules, which are from char.txt, word.txt, line.txt and sent.txt for, respectively, grapheme cluster, word, line and sentence breaks.

For the iterator on words, I could find a rule set defined only for "Swedish (Finland)" (`sv_FI`) in a later version (72.1). If you try it with your code and a more recent version of ICU, you will not get a warning.

Comment: I enabled sv_FI on my system and used it in place of en_US in my example, but still got the same warning.

Comment: In version 70.1, the one you are using, custom word-breaking rules for sv_FI were not yet present. In fact, in that specific version, there seem to be [no custom rules for word breakers](https://github.com/unicode-org/icu/tree/release-70-1/icu4c/source/data/brkitr/rules).